# Screen brightness flickering on a Samsung laptop

Tags: 12.04, screen, brightness, flicker

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04 via the wubi installer. I have Windows 7 installed as my main os. Now when i turn on my computer and go into Ubuntu my screen brightness is on max. When i then turn up the brightness the screen starts to flicker. It also shows thenindicator of how much brightness my screen have. I have a Intel core i5 with the Intel HD graphics 3000.

I hope you can help me, but so far i have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case samsung-backlight package solve problem. See [Brightness problem on a Samsung 530U3B](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167832/ubuntu-12-04-brightness-problem)
You have same vendor for video chipset so it may help you too.