# Brightness problem on a Samsung 530U3B

Tags: brightness, samsung, flicker

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on a Samsung 530U3B laptop. Screen blinks on adjusting the brightness and CPU load grow up to 100%.

Video device: Intel(R) Extreme Graphics 3 Controller.

Seems like it started after kernel upgrade to 3.2.0-27-generic-pae.

Comment: Experiencing the same issues on Samsung 900X3A.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to fix this problem by installing the `samsung-backlight` from [Linux on my Samsung PPA](https://launchpad.net/~voria/+archive/ppa/?field.series_filter=precise).

Comment: samsung-backlight is really helpful!!!  Thank you!

Comment: Works on 900X3A after reboot, but there's no brightness indicator anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Notebook NP530U3B.

I solved this:

```
cat /etc/madprobe.d/blacklist-samsung.conf
blacklist samsung_laptop
blacklist samsung_backlight #if you have
```