# Can't adjust screen brightness on Ubuntu 12.04LTS

Tags: 12.04, screen, brightness, samsung

My laptop is Samsung NP-Q430-JS03US. 
I have searched for the solution. I have tried editing grub `acpi_osi=Linux` and `acpi_backlight=vendor`, but still didn't work.

Please help.

Answer (score 6):

Try using `xbacklight`.

- Install it by running `sudo apt-get install xbacklight` in a terminal.
- Change brightness by `xbacklight -set <level>`, where `<level>` is an integer ranging from 0 to 100 (lowest brightness to highest).

For example, to set medium brightness one would use

```
xbacklight -set 50
```

Comment: this does not seem to work on Samsung laptops

Comment: This works for me in my Lenovo laptop. Thanks alot.

Comment: Does not work on my Lenovo laptop :(

Answer (score 1):

Your laptop is Optimus-enabled. That means that it has two video cards: an Intel card and a Nvidia one (meant to be used for games only). This is problematic because Optimus has been designed to work with Microsoft Windows, and Ubuntu won't play very good with it.

Please check your BIOS setup, whether the Optimus option is enabled or not --if there's even any Optimus settings.

With Optimus enabled, your display will be managed by the Intel card. The brightness controls should work out-of-the-box. The Nvidia card will be fully-powered all the time though, and you need to [setup Bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) to avoid this and to be able to use the Nvidia card for gaming.

With Optimus disabled, your display will be managed by the Nvidia card, and you'll lose the brightness controls, since the Nvidia card is not capable of accessing them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should sudo open `/etc/default/grub`, find the line that starts with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and make it look like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi=Linux i915.i915_enable_rc6=1″
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a Samsung NP300E5a with Optimus. Same problem after upgrading to Kernel 3.5.0-31-generic.
I found a solution that works for me here "[Brightness problem on a Samsung 530U3B](https://askubuntu.com/questions/167832/ubuntu-12-04-brightness-problem)". Details below

Add the "Linux On My Samsung" repository to the sources list:
Code:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:voria/ppa
Update the programs list:
```

Code:

```
sudo apt-get update
Install samsung-backlight:
```

Code:

```
sudo apt-get install samsung-backlight
Restart the system and check if backlight control works
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the non-free NVIDIA drivers from the Software Sources application? In that case:

Open a terminal and type:

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Scroll to the `Device` section in the text file that appears and add this line in it:

```
     Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1;"
```

Save the file.

Restart.

Comment: this worked for me on my 2010 macbook pro, thanks

Comment: I love you man!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with xbacklight with no exit. It did not recognized the program or similar (new user). However I tried with xrandrand it is perfect. I link the one I used. It is great and my eyes are happy [How to change LCD brightness from command line (or via script)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/149054/how-to-change-lcd-brightness-from-command-line-or-via-script)

Comment: Don't post just an link as an answer. Post the instuctions what to do with the link as a source.

Answer (score 0):

---->>>> TRY THIS CODE BY " PROFESSIONALS " <<<<<-----

Go to terminal

Type code : `cd /etc/default/`

Next it appears like /etc/default$

Type code :  `Sudo vim grub`

A will see a new window in that find the line like below and exit it .

code : `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

code : `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=\"Linux\""`

After completing editing save it by command like :wq press enter.

now edited window will be close and terminal will appears now type

code : `SUDO UPDATE GRUB`
code : `Next SUDO reboot`

now your Brightness will be changes . 
SUCCESS :-)